# Updating a SoftLayer ticket with a new comment using SL REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking at method SoftLayer_Ticket::addUpdate and it isn't obvious what JSON payload to include on the PUT and what the actual return from the update is.  Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Is right, use addUpdate method for add a new comment by SL REST API, the method returns a SoftLayer_Ticket_Update sent in the request body, I recommend use POST method in this request.
For more information, you could review the next link https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Ticket_Update/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I issued the following URL https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Ticket/addUpdate/87557470 with content of {
     "parameters" :
          {
             "entry" : "Test REST API update case"
          }
   }    with a method of POST.    I got the following,    RC 500 with MSG of "Internal Server Error"  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the request is bad.
Following the next request
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Ticket/87557470/addUpdate
POST

BODY
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "entry":"Only test tech support2",
         "type":  
            {  
               "keyName":"AGENT"
            }
      }
   ]
}